# Android Studio / Mis vistas del recycler-view se compactan ¿Por que?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

En la imágen se puede ver un gráfico (el superior) el cual muestra como se ve mi layout en la **vista diseño**. El gráfico de debajo es el resultado al ejecutar la app **en mi dispositivo**. No se por que sucede este "estrechamiento".

**Adjunto el código xml de las vistas de el recycler view**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:text="Texto 1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Texto 2"    
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imgbt"  
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txt_1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imgbt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_negro"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imgbt_reservar_item_row_recycler_dias"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:text="button"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Me gustaría que me indiquen que debería modificar para que las vistas del Recycler View se adapten a el ancho de la pantalla o al menos a lo que yo le indico en el código XML**

**Desde ya, muchas gracias por leer.**

Comment: pues es que estas dando un ancho de "wrap_content" a los textos y al imagenbotón. Deberías darle ancho y alto definidos en dp, así como en el botón

Comment: Creo que lo que decis no tiene sentido.  Nunca funcionó de esa manera, y si fuese así, las vistas no podrían ser dinámicas, puesto que si un text view de 50dp recibe texto que sea más largo que esos 50dp simplemente no entraría en la vista del Text View. Aún así te agradezco por responder.

Comment: Has probado a poner margenes entre los controles? No solo con el top y los lados laterales, sino entre ellos.

Comment: Si. No funcionó.

Comment: @armen no esta tan equivocado, se te ve asi porque tenes todo en wrapcontent, entonces usa el menor espacio posible para mostrarse. No te recomiendo que pongas un ancho fijo, porque no seria muy dinamico, pero una mejor solucion seria poner todo en un linearlayout, dejar todo en wrapcontent excepto el segundo textView, ese ponele width=0 y weight = 1. Eso hara toda la magia

Comment: Lo acabo de probar como decís y no funciona tampoco. Se siguen viendo compactadas. :( Por favor alguien que me ayude

Comment: El problema es en el contenedor de esta vista, agregalo por favor. @TomasM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que debes definir las reglas del [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) correctamente. Cuando tienes vistas las cuales quieres adaptar a los limites de la pantalla, con proporciones diferentes, debes definir las reglas de forma que cada una cumpla con las condiciones que quieres.

En tu caso, al parecer quieres establecer porcentajes o tamaños según tu percepción, por tanto, es importante tener claro las reglas que vas a definir.

- **Reglas para el ancho de la vista (Width)**:

> app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf: Indica donde empieza la vista a
> partir del comienzo de otra. Ejemplo: Empieza a dibujar donde empiece
> la vista X.
>
> app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf: Indica donde termina la vista a
> partir de la terminacion de otra. Ejemplo: Termina el ancho donde
> termina la vista X.
>
> app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf: Indica donde empieza la vista a
> partir de la terminacion de otra. Ejemplo: Empieza a dibujar donde
> termina una vista X.
>
> app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf: Indica donde termina la vista a
> partir del comienzo de otra. Ejemplo: Termina el ancho donde empieza
> una vista X.

Por ejemplo, digamos que quieres crear una vista con las siguientes proporciones en tu **ConstraintLayout**:

Dos vistas con proporciones iguales en el ancho total del contenedor:

> parent|<---(`view1`)--->|<--- (`view2`)--->|parent

Tus hijos del [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) deberían tener reglas definidas así:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/view2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**NOTA IMPORTANTE:** Las vistas que se definen con `android:layout_width="0dp"` dentro de `ConstraintLayout` indican que tomaran todo el espacio disponible, para las restricciones asignadas.

**view1:** dice que tiene restricción al inicio con el padre (Empezara a dibujarse desde ahi). Restriccion al final con `view2` (terminara donde empieza `view2`).

**view2:** dice que tiene restricción de inicio al final de **view1** (empezara a dibujarse donde termine view1). Restricción al final con parent (terminara donde termine el padre, es decir al final del contenedor).

Lógicamente, son dos vistas que se compactan en un mismo espacio, por lo cual, tomara todo ese espacio disponible que las compacta y las dividirá en dos partes iguales, de modo que el resultado son dos vistas que ocupan el 50% total del ancho del contenedor cada una.

Así mismo, si quieres tener varias vistas en un contenedor que ocupen partes iguales a excepción de una que definas un tamaño, simplemente define las reglas necesarias para cumplir con las restricciones y asignale a tu vista en particular un tamaño especifico:

Ejemplo:

```
            0dp          0dp               200dp
parent|<---view1---><---view2---><---------view3-------->|parent
```

pues tendrías algo como esto en código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### Solución

Para que llegues a tu solución, debes definir todas las reglas necesarias para cumpla con tu restricción. Solo tienes definidas algunas, pero no todas para que cumplan con el diseño que quieres. Por ejemplo, en tu `Button` tienes `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"`, pero Donde esta la regla de `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf` ?. De igual modo las demas vistas le faltan reglas. Te lo dejo de tarea, happy coding!.

Comment: Que buena respuesta. Muy completa. Ya lo pude solucionar, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Creo que te puedo ayudar. Probe algo parecido a lo que dices que tiene y me ocupa la mayor cantidad de espacio posible gracias a las **chains**. Logre algo como esto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si le modificas un poco los margenes puedes ver que ocupa todo el espacio. Esta propiedad esta en el diseñador de Android Studio. Como puedes ver en la foto no existe la horizontal puesto que la añadi para lograr que ocupara todo el espacio pero te debe salir sin problemas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Tienes que seleccionar todos los items que qieras agruegarlos a la cadena. Luego de esto si te fijas bien tienes una opcion de cambiar la modalidad. Experimenta un poco con los estilos y fijate al que se adapte mejor a lo que deseas. Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Gracias hermano!!!